# Hive SQL query to extract distinct records with multiple linked batch ids

Tags: hive

I have a table with 250+ columns with columns like `batchid, impressionid,` etc. This table is populated depending on batches, and each entry has a distinct batch id. The `impressionid` could now have several batchids and could have various columns altered. I need a query that will return `impressionid` entries with only one batchid connected as well as position IDs with multiple batchids which has multiple batchids I would need the one with maximum batchid.

I tried to do this

```
select * 
from my_table org 
join 
    (select impressionid, max(batchid) as max_batchid 
     from my_table a 
     group by impressionid) on org.impressionid = a.impressionid 
                            and org.batchid = a.max_batchid
```

But I get the output which is missing the records of `impressionid`  with multiple batches.

I have around a million distinct `impressionids` for a particular date.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.